# How do I install Image::Magick on Debian etch?

Tags: perl, debian, imagemagick, etch

I've been trying to install Image::Magick on Debian etch for a while without great success.

I've got `graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` installed, but can't find the `.deb` for Perl's `Image::Magick.` And `cpan -i Image::Magick` gives me all sorts of compilation errors.

Does anyone know the good combination of software so I can finally write `use Image::Magick`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've got the answer: The package to install is **perlmagick**.
I hope it doesn't help just me :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `libgraphics-magick-perl`?

EDIT:

Are you sure you need the real deal?

`perlmagick` contains its own version of `Image::Magick`.

Comment: Yes, but it contains Graphics::Magick , not Image::Magick . And my product needs Image::Magick (movabletype)