# ImageMagick API for command-line GUI application interface to `display`

Tags: linux, api, user-interface, command-line, imagemagick

I'd like to, basically, have a quick way to select a box (region of interest) in an image, and get geometry output in ImageMagick's format. I cannot see an easy way to do it with the default ImageMagick `display` viewer, so I'm looking for some API (and hopefully examples) to allow me to code my own viewer.

A bit of background: In [ImageMagick • View topic - selecting a region of interest from command line](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=12267&start=0) (2008) it is said you cannot do it, however, there is [display: ImageMagick - Region of Interest](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/display.html#regi) (2003?) which explains how to do it (but apparently it refers to an older version).

Anyways, this is how things look is you call `display -size 300x500 pattern:checkerboard` (*`pattern:checkerboard` is built-in pattern image in imagemagick*):

[image: imagemagick display ROI]

Once the "ImageMagick" display window is up, click on it; then Command menu shows - from it, choose /"Image Edit"/"Region of Interest..."; then can click and drag on the viewer display window. And you also get the geometry in upper left corner - but you cannot copy/paste it as text (so I've had to retype).

Also, `display` in command line mode takes up the terminal ([linux - Make imagemagick's `display` exit at terminal, preserving the window (single instance mode) - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/426176/make-imagemagicks-display-exit-at-terminal-preserving-the-window-single-ins#comment489030_426176)) - and I cannot see a way to force it to run in "single instance mode", such that I could issue filenames on the command line, and `display` would load them in the one and the same currently running instance.

Now, I've found [Casting spells with ImageMagick - Image manipulation for programmers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-imagemagick/index.html#prog_manipulation) (2012), which mentions a MagickWand API; after some searching, I found on the `imagemagick` site:

- [ImageMagick: MagickWand, C API for ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php)
- [ImageMagick: MagickCore, Low-level C API for ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-core.php?ImageMagick=ilvg2dv5rhem7jttol79c6h8j2)
- [ImageMagick: PerlMagick, Perl API for ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php)
- [ImageMagick: Magick++, C++ API for ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php)

So, my first thought was a script in Python - but apparently there is only a Perl API, which is fine.

However, what I need to code is basically a command line interface, which will start a `display` -like window process as a "single instance", and exit the terminal while passing parameters such as file name, `-density` etc to the window; the window would then react on mouse clicks, allowing selection of a crop geometry box (region of interest) - and finally, render the geometry string in a text box, so you can copy it. But as far as I can see, all the APIs are oriented toward performing the functions of the command-line `convert`.

So my question is - can any of these API's be used to program a `display`-like GUI; and do there exist any examples of a similar nature (*preferably in a scripting language, but I'll live with C/C++*) which can be pointed out?

Many thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Comment: Possibly related: [linux - ImageMagick DisplayImages() for Windows? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228050/imagemagick-displayimages-for-windows)

Comment: There was a guy working on a Windows GUI but have not seen any results as I have a 32bit Windows system and he was developing for 64bit. The thread in the Imagemagik forum is here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18219&hilit=gui May or may not be of help - he is the developer of combine ZP.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Command line SVG and image file viewer in Linux? - Super User](http://superuser.com/a/225465/39752); [A "quick" vector editor (SVG) for Linux (for annotating images?) - Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/352816/a-quick-vector-editor-svg-for-linux-for-annotating-images)

Answer (score 4):

Well, this turned out to be a bit of a pain, but I managed to put together a Perl-Tk script with ImageMagick API, that behaves like what I wanted: [imgckdis.pl](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/imgckdis.pl) (*code also below*). Here is a [screenshot](http://sdaaubckp.sourceforge.net/post/img/imgckdispl.png):

[image: imgckdispl.png]

Note that it can pretty much just display an image in hardcoded 400x400 px (although it may extend for bigger images) - there is no menus, no mouse interaction (scrollwheel zoom) - pretty much nothing :) The script only accepts one command-line argument - a file to be opened; but it can also understand ImageMagick specials like "xc:white" (*the ImageMagick portion will even automatically render SVG files, as shown on screenshot*).

But one thing it is capable of, is working in single instance mode: the first instance started becomes a "master", and draws the Tk window, and locks the respective terminal. Subsequent instances of the script, realizing the master instance is already started, will simply issue a command to the master to load a new image.

This "issuing a command to 'master'" turned out to be not so easy, as the collection of links below shows (as well as the revision notes in the online [vesrion](http://sdaaubckp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/imgckdis.pl)). I thought at first, that using interprocess-communication shared variables would allow me to store a "pointer by reference" to the master; and then allow the subsequent instances to call functions on it. Well, it seems that cannot be done - for one, [Perl may discourage that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668453/ipcshareable-variables-cant-use-string-as-a-scalar-ref-and-memory-ad) - but even if you hop over all those checks, in the end you get a memory address which is not seen as in shared space, and so one cannot retrieve anything from it. Furthermore, the `IPC::Shareable` Perl package is possibly "guaranteed" only for integers and strings ?!

Nevertheless, the approach that finally worked is, as hinted, to have the "master" poll for changes in changed variables; and non-master instances to simply change this variable when they are called - and this approach seems to work... However, for a "real" application, one would then have to think of organizing quite a few of these shared variables..

Well, maybe one cannot still zoom and reposition the image, and draw a geometry rectangle - but, at least it's an example that can be demonstrated to be working (at least on Ubuntu) `:)`...

Hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# imgckdis.pl
# http://sdaaubckp.svn.sf.net/viewvc/sdaaubckp/single-scripts/imgckdis.pl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Image::Magick; # sudo apt-get install perlmagick # debian/ubuntu
use Tk;
use MIME::Base64;

use Carp;
use Fcntl ':flock';

use Data::Printer;
use Class::Inspector;

use IPC::Shareable;


my $amMaster = 1;
my $file_read;

open my $self, '<', $0 or die "Couldn't open self: $!";
flock $self, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB or $amMaster = 0;

if ($amMaster == 1) {
  print "We are master single instance as per flock\n";
  IPC::Shareable->clean_up_all;
}

if (!$ARGV[0]) {
  $file_read = "xc:white";
} else {
  $file_read = $ARGV[0];
}
chomp $file_read;


my %options = (
  create    => 1,
  exclusive => 0,
  mode      => 0644,
  destroy   => 0,
);

my $glue1 = 'dat1';
my $glue2 = 'dat2';

my $refcount;
my $reffname;
my $lastreffname;

my $refcount_handle = tie $refcount, 'IPC::Shareable', $glue1 , \%options ;
if ($amMaster == 1) {
  $refcount = undef;
}

my $reffname_handle = tie $reffname, 'IPC::Shareable', $glue2 , \%options ;
if ($amMaster == 1) {
  $reffname = undef;
}

my ($image, $blob, $content, $tkimage, $mw);


if ($amMaster == 1) { # if (not(defined($refcount))) {
  # initialize the assigns
  $lastreffname = "";

  $reffname_handle->shlock(LOCK_SH|LOCK_NB);
  $reffname = $file_read; #
  $reffname_handle->shunlock();

  $refcount_handle->shlock(LOCK_SH|LOCK_NB);
  $refcount = 1; #
  $refcount_handle->shunlock();
}

# mainly from http://objectmix.com/perl/771215-how-display-image-magick-image-tk-canvas.html
sub generateImageContent() {
  #fake a PGM then convert it to gif
  $image = Image::Magick->new(
    size => "400x400",
  );
  $image->Read($file_read); #("xc:white");
  $image->Draw(
    primitive => 'line',
    points => "300,100 300,500",
    stroke => '#600',
  );
  # set it as PGM
  $image->Set(magick=>'pgm');

  #your pgm is loaded here, now change it to gif or whatever
  $image->Set(magick=>'gif');
  $blob = $image->ImageToBlob();

  # Tk wants base64encoded images
  $content = encode_base64( $blob ) or die $!;
}

sub loadImageContent() {
  #fake a PGM then convert it to gif
  $image = Image::Magick->new(
    size => "400x400",
  );
  $image->Read($lastreffname); #("xc:red") for test

  # set it as PGM
  $image->Set(magick=>'pgm');

  #your pgm is loaded here, now change it to gif or whatever
  $image->Set(magick=>'gif');
  $blob = $image->ImageToBlob();

  # Tk wants base64encoded images
  $content = encode_base64( $blob ) or die $!;

  #~ $tkimage->read($content); # expects filename
  $tkimage->put($content); # works!
}


sub CleanupExit() {
  # only one remove() passes - the second fails: "Couldn't remove shared memory segment/semaphore set"
  (tied $refcount)->remove();
  IPC::Shareable->clean_up;
  $mw->destroy();
  print "Exiting appliction!\n";
  exit;
}

sub updateVars() {
  if ( not($reffname eq $lastreffname) ) {
    print "Change: ", $lastreffname, " -> ", $reffname, "\n";
    $lastreffname = $reffname;
    loadImageContent();
  }
}

if ( not($amMaster == 1) ) {
  # simply set the shared variable to cmdarg variable
  # (master's updateVars should take care of update)
  $reffname_handle->shlock(LOCK_SH|LOCK_NB);
  $reffname = $file_read;
  $reffname_handle->shunlock();

  # and exit now - we don't want a second instance
  print "Main instance of this script is already running\n";
  croak "Loading new file: $file_read";
}


$mw = MainWindow->new();
$mw->protocol(WM_DELETE_WINDOW => sub { CleanupExit(); } );

generateImageContent();
$tkimage = $mw->Photo(-data => $content);

$mw->Label(-image => $tkimage)->pack(-expand => 1, -fill => 'both');
$mw->Button(-text => 'Quit', -command => sub { CleanupExit(); } )->pack;

# polling function for sharable - 100 ms
$mw->repeat(100, \&updateVars);


MainLoop;



__END__
```

Relevant links:

- [How to display an Image::Magick image in a Tk::Canvas?](http://objectmix.com/perl/771215-how-display-image-magick-image-tk-canvas.html)
- [Installing the Perl Image::Magick module on CentOS 5.2 (Fourmilog: None Dare Call It Reason)](http://www.fourmilab.ch/fourmilog/archives/2008-12/001099.html)
- [perl - How do I install Image::Magick on Debian etch? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260663/how-do-i-install-imagemagick-on-debian-etch)
- [[magick-users] PerlMagick 6.0.0 Composite -opacity doesn't work](http://studio.imagemagick.org/pipermail/magick-users/2004-May/012679.html)
- [Ensuring only one copy of a perl script is running at a time](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=590619)
- [Re: Limiting a program to a single running instance - nntp.perl.org](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.beginners/2007/10/msg95773.html)
- [Sys::RunAlone - search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/~elizabeth/Sys-RunAlone-0.12/lib/Sys/RunAlone.pm)
- [What's the best way to make sure only one instance of a Perl program is running? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455911/whats-the-best-way-to-make-sure-only-one-instance-of-a-perl-program-is-running)
- [reinstall PERL - PERL Beginners (Do you need to predeclare croak?)](http://www.justskins.com/forums/reinstall-perl-16399.html)
- [Image in Perl TK?](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=731610)
- [Perl Tk::Photo help](http://x10hosting.com/forums/programming-help/92296-perl-tk-photo-help.html)
- [introspection - How do I list available methods on a given object or package in Perl? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910430/how-do-i-list-available-methods-on-a-given-object-or-package-in-perl)
- [Can't install IPC:Shareable](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=879713)
- [Share variables between Child processes in perl without IPC::Shareable - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879797/share-variables-between-child-processes-in-perl-without-ipcshareable)
- [IPC::Shareable - search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/~bsugars/IPC-Shareable-0.60/lib/IPC/Shareable.pm)
- [perl - Checking IPC Shareable lock - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166063/checking-ipc-shareable-lock)
- [Storing complex data structures using Storable](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=819999)
- [using tie on two arrays on IPC::Shareable makes array1 and array2 both same even though array2 is not updated.](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=799539)
- [Dereferencing in perl](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/dereferencing.html)
- [Shared Memory using IPC::Shareable - Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=823756)
- [Re: Handling child process and close window exits in Perl/Tk](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=578304)
- [How can I convert the stringified version of array reference to actual array reference in Perl? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1671495/277826)
- [Re: IPC::Shareable Problem with multidimentional hash](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Perl/comp.lang.perl.misc/2005-09/msg00667.html)
- [perl - IPC::Shareable variables, "Can't use string ... as a SCALAR ref.." and memory address - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668453/ipcshareable-variables-cant-use-string-as-a-scalar-ref-and-memory-ad)
- [Perl/Tk App and Interprocess Communication](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=470827)
- [Re: Antw: Re: Perl/Tk + Thread - nntp.perl.org](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.beginners/2003/05/msg47199.html)